# Get months from dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date, lubridate, tibble

I have this tibble with a bunch of dates, below is a sample of the tibble.

```
library(tibble); library(lubridate)

c("25/10/1952", "27/05/1961", "07/11/1962", "20/12/1963", "15/01/1966", "12/02/1966", "12/05/1966", "11/11/1967", "14/01/1975", "17/10/1976", "05/11/1981", "03/11/1982", "14/11/1982", "12/10/1984", "24/12/1988", "26/10/1998", "11/11/2003", "14/12/2003") -> start

c("08/11/1952", "27/05/1961", "07/11/1962", "28/12/1963", "10/03/1966", "05/03/1966", "12/05/1966", "16/11/1967", "15/02/1975", "30/10/1976", "05/11/1981", "16/11/1982", "18/11/1982", "12/10/1984", "29/12/1988", "28/10/1998", "12/11/2003", "02/02/2004") -> finish

tibble(start = as.Date(dmy(start)), finish = as.Date(dmy(finish))) -> df
```

I need to get unique months contained in either column. So the output from the above would be this:

```
January, February, March, May, October, November, December
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the months output in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  distinct(month = month(value, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)) %>% 
  arrange(month)

# A tibble: 7 × 1
  month   
  <ord>   
1 January 
2 February
3 March   
4 May     
5 October 
6 November
7 December
```

Bonus, count numnber of occurences:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  count(month = month(value, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE), name = "count") 

# A tibble: 7 × 2
  month    count
  <ord>    <int>
1 January      2
2 February     3
3 March        2
4 May          4
5 October      7
6 November    13
7 December     5
```

Answer (score 2):

### Base R

Based on @thelatemail's note that you want unique months as result, do `sort(factor(unique(unlist(lapply(df, format, "%B"))), month.name))`. Written as pipe:

```r
lapply(df, format, "%B") |>
  unlist() |>
  unique() |>
  factor(x = _, month.name) |>
  sort()
```

gives

```r
[1] January  February March    May      October  November December
Levels: January February March April May June July August September October November December
```

Wrap in `paste(place_here, collapse = ", ")`, if the result should be a of length one where months are comma-separated.

---

Data:

```r
df = data.frame(start = as.Date(c("25/10/1952", "27/05/1961", "07/11/1962", "20/12/1963", "15/01/1966", "12/02/1966", "12/05/1966", "11/11/1967", "14/01/1975", "17/10/1976", "05/11/1981", "03/11/1982", "14/11/1982", "12/10/1984", "24/12/1988", "26/10/1998", "11/11/2003", "14/12/2003")), 
                finish = as.Date(c("08/11/1952", "27/05/1961", "07/11/1962", "28/12/1963", "10/03/1966", "05/03/1966", "12/05/1966", "16/11/1967", "15/02/1975", "30/10/1976", "05/11/1981", "16/11/1982", "18/11/1982", "12/10/1984", "29/12/1988", "28/10/1998", "12/11/2003", "02/02/2004")))
```

Comment: This is 95% of it, but I think OP wants just the `unique` months represented. `df` already has Date columns too, so you can drop the `as.Date`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `read.table` (thanks for the [data from @Friede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77909597/12158757))

```
> month.name[sort(unique(read.table(text = unlist(df), sep = "/")$V2))]
[1] "January"  "February" "March"    "May"      "October"  "November" "December"
```

or `gsub`

```
> month.name[as.numeric(sort(unique(gsub("^\\d+/|/\\d+$", "", unlist(df)))))]
[1] "January"  "February" "March"    "May"      "October"  "November" "December"
```